# jquery disable input fields in hidden div

Tags: jquery

I have a form with inputs in div which are hidden via CSS (display:none;)
Once a checkbox is ticked, the div become visible and the field id="quantity" is displayed.

I need this field to be required, once they are displayed.

How do I do this?

```
<style>
.quantitydiv
    {display:none;}
</style>


<input type="checkbox" name="product" id="check1" onclick="Quantity()">Product
<div class="quantitydiv">                                        
<input type="text" id="quantity">
<i>(quantity)</i>
</div>
```

I tried jquery, but not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".quantitydiv").show().find("input").prop("required", true);
$(".quantitydiv").hide().find("input").prop("required", false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: where's the checkbox?

Comment: "_Once a checkbox is ticked, the div become visible_" please proofread your code few times before posting it.

Comment: I added the checkbox, that activates a javascript function Quantity() onclick which changes CSS for .quantitydiv to display:block;

Comment: Your code as shown above shows and then hides the div. in document.ready. Please show the 'Quantity()' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
              $("#quantity").prop("required", true);
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
               $("#quantity").prop("required", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice! This will work too.. Only issue, my checkbox id is not constant. id="check1", "check2", "check3" etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this could be your HTML with the checkbox which is missing

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product" id="check1">Product
<div class="quantitydiv">
  <input type="text" id="quantity">
  <i>(quantity)</i>
</div>
```

this JS code should actually do the trick

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const checkbox = $("#check1");
  const hiddenArea = $(".quantitydiv");
  const areaTextInput = hiddenArea.find('input');

  hiddenArea.hide();

  checkbox.on('change', (e) => {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hiddenArea.show();
      areaTextInput.prop('required', true);
    } else {
      hiddenArea.hide();
      areaTextInput.prop('required', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you this looks good! Only issue I have is the id="show-qty" is not a constant in my html, id="check1", check2, check3, etc. about 50 different checkboxes

Comment: @northernlights I've updated my answer before with the correct selector for `#check1`. if you have multiple checks I suggest you to identify them by using classes, and identify related `<div class="quantitydiv">` with a `.data` attribute or a `quantitydiv-${index}` sort of thing classname